# Как записать в файл две коллекции, чтобы потом можно было загрузить их и использовать в дальнейшем? C#

Tags: c#, коллекции, save

У меня имеются две коллекции содержащие целые числа(координаты точек на плоскости):

```
List<int> x = new List<int>();
List<int> y = new List<int>();
```

Каким образом записать их в файл, а потом загрузить?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: в две строки через запятую? `File.WriteAllLines(myFile, new []{string.Join(',', x)}, string.Join(',', y)});`?

Comment: а вообще надо пояснить, что это за данные, зачем вам они в файле, что ещё кроме этого вы в файл хотите записать, как вы эти данные использовать собрались? без этого вопрос неполный, на неполный вопрос получите неполный ответ.

Comment: @tym32167  Пишу программу, к-ая из заданного множества точек на плоскости(сохраняю координаты точек в коллекции) выбирает две точки так, чтобы построить чз них прямую, к-ая в свою очередь поделит множество точек поровну(см. скрин)

Коллекции используются в следующей формуле:
double D = (x[m] - x[i]) * (y[j] - y[i]) - (y[m] - y[i]) * (x[j] - x[i]);

Comment: В данном случае, если вам надо только точки сохранить, то я бы написал класс Point(x, y) и сохранял бы коллекцию точек List<Point> при помощи сериализации (например, XML сериализации).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Читать тут](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/serialization/)

[И тут](https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/6.2.php)

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

//Не забудь подключить
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;

namespace PlaygroundCS
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }


        private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Твоя коллекция точек
            List<PointF> myCollections = new List<PointF>();

            //Класс необходимый для сериализации и десериализации
            BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();

            //Запись
            using (FileStream file = new FileStream("dataFile.dat", FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
            {
                formatter.Serialize(file, myCollections);

                MessageBox.Show("Объект записан в файл!");
            }

            //Чтение
            using (FileStream file = new FileStream("dataFile.dat", FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
            {
                List<PointF> myCollectionsFromFile = (List<PointF>)formatter.Deserialize(file);

                MessageBox.Show("Объект считан из файла!");
            }
        }
    }
}
```